# how to connect to google server through android application after i factory reset my phone

Tags: android

G+ login through android application is easy when i am already having an email id in my phone but when i factory reset it GoogleApiClient not calling connect method as now my phone is with no gmail id login currently
So how to make it connect again after resetting?
Is anyone with idea?
Here's some source code i used for Google+ login:-

Connecting on Button Click

```
btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        });
```

When connection is not successful

```
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {

        if (!mIntentInProgress && arg0.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                arg0.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }
```

OnActivity result

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode,
                                    Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            mIntentInProgress = false;
            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() && responseCode==-1) {
                Log.d("Flag",mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()+"res"+responseCode);
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
             }

        } 
    }
```

When getting connected,Fetching image and name of login person

```
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
            Person person = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            Log.d("Welcome : ", person.getDisplayName());
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(person.getImage()
                        .toString());
                String imageUrl = jsonObject.getString("url");
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
                    Bitmap bmp;
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                            .getInputStream());
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                    Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                    i1.putExtra("image", byteArray);
                    i1.putExtra("name", person.getDisplayName());
                    i1.putExtra("count", "2");
                    startActivity(i1);
                    finish();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you asking about providing a new email for signing in with your app?

Comment: What i want is as-App as not finding any account login in phone may redirect me to add account option(SignUp)or some pop up after a certain interval if not getting connected.I want to notify user about this basically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your device doesnt have any gmail account integrated with it for now, it will call the following method after trying to get connected

```
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {

    if (!mIntentInProgress && arg0.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            mIntentInProgress = true;
            arg0.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

            mIntentInProgress = false;
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
    else {
          //you can do whatever you want in this block,like adding a dialog, navigating to sign up etc..
        }
}
```

Hope this is exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for help.Working fine